# Ember-simple-auth Session Expiring when I refresh the Page

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

> / app / login / controller.js

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { inject } from '@ember/service';

export default Controller.extend({
    session: inject('session'),
    actions: {
        authenticate: function(){
            // let _this = this;
            let credentials = this.getProperties('identification','password');
            let authenticator = 'authenticator:jwt';
            this.get('session').authenticate(authenticator, credentials).catch((reason)=>{
                // this.set('errorMessage', reason.error || reason);
                this.set('errorMessage','Login Failed');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

> /app / profile / controller.js

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { inject } from '@ember/service';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Controller.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
    session: inject('session'),
});
```

> / config / environment.js

```
.....

ENV['ember-simple-auth'] = {
    authorizer: 'authorizer:custom',
    routeAfterAuthentication: '/profiles',
  };


....
```

When I logged in with the necessary credentials it will route to the **Profile Route** and then when I refresh the page, the session expires,
Suggest a solution,

Comment: From above you need to move the mixin import to your route.  Check the docs for application route etc.

Comment: @rossjha To be honest I don't understand anything what you said

Comment: Here’s the link.  There should also be a good dummy app in the addon for you to reference https://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/AuthenticatedRouteMixin.html

Comment: actually the I found what is exactly the problem,

Comment: The problem is I haven't provide the store session

Comment: can anyone help how to do it?